# How to update DocumentReference?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I tried to update DocumentReference but could not do it.

`update()` method fails. How to use it? (How to pass argument?)

`firebase-admin` version is 6.3.0.
`@google-cloud/firestore` version is 0.19.0.

```
❯ firebase functions:shell
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v8.14.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
✔  functions: sampleFunc
firebase > const admin = require('firebase-admin');
firebase > admin.initializeApp();
firebase > let ref = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc('edqupYQhzqV1ODjEpoJn');
firebase > let updates = { email: 'xxx@yyy.zzz' };
firebase > ref.update(updates).then(value => console.log(value) );
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    at WriteBatch.update (/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:359:23)
    at DocumentReference.update (/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:387:14)
```

**Update**
Document has already been created, so `get()` works.

```
firebase > ref.get().then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.data()));
```

Errors also occur in `set()` as well.

```
firebase > ref.set({email: 'aaa@bbb.ccc'}, {merge: true}).then(value => console.log(value));
Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    at Validator.(anonymous function).values [as isDocument] (/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:99:27)
    at WriteBatch.set (/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:232:25)
    at DocumentReference.set (/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:349:27)
```

Comment: were you ever able to get this solved?

Answer (score 3):

Following the example you posted, you are trying to update a document that does not exist. In this case you should create it first.

If you're not sure whether the document exists, pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents.

From Google's Documentation:

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

var setWithOptions = cityRef.set({
  capital: true
}, {merge: true});
```

Reference: [Firestore Add Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of information.
Document has already been created, so `get()` works.
I added more information to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried using the Admin SDK in the functions:shell like you do in your example. However I can easily reproduce your error. I guess that the functions:shell somehow tampers with your variable `updates`. When i log `updates` undefined is concatenated in output

```
firebase > console.log(updates)
{ email2: 'xxx@yyy.zzz' }
undefined
```

If you put your code in a JS file, initialize your app with a service account and run in with node it will most likely work just fine!

[Read more about how to use Service Account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)

Answer (score 0):

create an object first then assign your values to a field/property on that object like:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj["myfield"] = myvalue;
```

now pass as the 2nd argument of `.set` or `.update`.